# Using Windows 10 as only operating system on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp

I recently installed Windows 10 on my MacBook Air (early 2015) with Boot Camp, and Windows lags a lot on it.

I thought of deleting macOS completely to see if Windows will run smoothly, is it a good idea? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Deleting macOS won't make Windows faster. How much RAM does your MacBook Air have? Can you be more specific when Windows is slow (web browsing, gaming, using Office/Teams, etc)?

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. If you have a hard drive, then that is most definetely the issue. A slow cpu or low ram might also give issues. Having 2 OSs shouldn’t really be the issue.

Comment: Bootcamp or Virtual machine?

Comment: It may depend on whether you have the base model 4GB or the upgraded 8GB RAM. 4GB is just not enough to run Windows 10 properly. As mentioned, whilst the Mac is running Windows, macOS has no influence at all, so removing it will not help.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed Windows via Boot Camp, your MacBook will boot into Windows „natively“ and work like any other laptop with Windows. Removing macOS will not change the performance you get under Windows.